# Benefits of using SVG 'use' tag

Tags: performance, svg, tags

Im doing a bit of research on SVG 'use' tag & I wonder if it can help in our particular scenario, i.e. lots of tiny crystals (svg objects) a user can create (as a rough estimate, I expect around 200-400 svg objects to be created per scenario).

My question is:

What are the benefits of using the 'use' tag, sure, it clones another object but as our app. can get pretty heavy, is there any performance benefit related to the 'use' tag?

Thanks,

Comment: From my experience <use> tends to make performance worse. The UA must keep track of what's referring to what in case all the instances need updating.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. That makes sense. In our case, there need not be a relationship between the SVG objs. so we can ignore 'use' tag for now.

Comment: In Opera at least, the internal objects created by use instances are more lightweight than regular DOM nodes. There's a cost with maintaining the instance trees, but typically it's not too bad as long as the templates don't change.

Comment: Thanks @ErikDahlström. We are having quite a few problems with Opera (it seems to want to do everything differently to Gecko, Webkit browsers). We'll go ahead and do a test case scenario.